# The -o parameter in aria2c can't rename the downloaded file

Tags: command-line, file-sharing, bittorrent

```
aria2c -S  /home/se.torrent

Files:    
idx|path/length    
===+===========================================================================
1|./test.mkv        
 |283MiB (297,429,086)
```

---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I want to save the downloaded file as  ok.mkv in /tmp.

```
aria2c -d   /tmp  -o  ok.mkv    /home/se.torrent
```

The  downloaded name  can't be changed into  /tmp/ok.mkv ,it is still
/tmp/test.mkv  when the command executed.
[image]

In manual of `aria2c -h` ,there is no  strings such as:
 `NOTE:
      You  cannot  specify  a  file name for Metalink or BitTorrent
      downloads.`

Comment: The string is contained in the man pages as I have detailed below, which are accessed by running the command `man aria2c`. Hope that clears it up for you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are out of luck when attempting to rename `.torrent` files with `aria2c`, from the man pages:

```
 -o, --out=<FILE>
      The   file name of the downloaded file. When the
      --force-sequential option is used, this option is ignored.

      NOTE:
      You  cannot  specify  a  file name for Metalink or BitTorrent
      downloads.
```

Note that this information is *not* contained in the help given with the command:

```
aria2c -h
```

but in *the man pages* that are read with the following:

```
man aria2c
```

With other types of files `aria2c` works very nicely and appropriately renames as directed:

```
andrew@athens:~$ aria2c -d $HOME/test -o testing.jpg http://www.andrews-corner.org/images/fluxbox.jpg
[#3f8528 32KiB/417KiB(7%) CN:1 DL:87KiB ETA:4s]                                               
06/24 18:29:14 [NOTICE] Download complete: /home/andrew/test/testing.jpg

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
3f8528|OK  |   312KiB/s|/home/andrew/test/testing.jpg

Status Legend:
(OK):download completed.
```

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news...

Comment: In manual of `aria2c -h` ,there is no  strings such as `NOTE:
      You  cannot  specify  a  file name for Metalink or BitTorrent
      downloads.` did you add it?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Did I add it in a quest for reputation points? No :). You have not looked at the `man` pages which are accessed from the Terminal by typing in: `man aria2c`, the information is there... If you read to the bottom of the text given in `aria2c -h` you will see a pointer to this that reads: `Refer to man page for more information.`